# How I can set the Connect perm to default in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
client.on('message', (rw) => {
 if (rw.content.startsWith('#vban')) {
  if (!rw.member.hasPermission('MOVE_MEMBERS'))
   return rw.channel.send("**Check you're perms** | ❎ ");
  let men = rw.mentions.users.first();
  let mas = rw.author;
  if (!men) return rw.channel.send('`Mention the member `');
  rw.guild.channels.forEach((c) => {
   c.overwritePermissions(men.id, {
    CONNECT: `**(I want set the connect to the default perm)**`,
   });
  });
 }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a permission overwrite to "default" by calling `GuildChannel#updateOverwrite()` and passing `null` into the specific permission you want to overwrite.

Example:

```js
message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
  SEND_MESSAGES: null
})
```

relevant docs specification: [click here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite)